# How to set php config file (php.ini) to be used in phpmyadmin container in laradock

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose, laradock

My problem is I want to load a custom php.ini file in phpmyadmin container inside docker because I want to change max_execution_time and upload_temp_dir in php config file used by phpmyadmin.

Why I want to change it, because each time I import sql dump file (*sql) inside phpmyadmin, it always says like this

```
No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration. See FAQ 1.16.
```

I have tried to googling about phpmyadmin error above, many answers told me to change my php config file but I don't know the way to change that file using docker-compose. Any answers will be appreciated. thanks.

I am using laradock with docker-compose (of course)

Answer (score 2):

The way to solve it:

```
// Login to container
docker-compose exec phpmyadmin bash

// Install vim
apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim

// Update ini(s)
php --ini

// Check results and update phpmyadmin conf
vim /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development
vim /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production

// Update fields 
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M


// Restart all containers
exit;
docker-compose restart
```